# Is it possible to use nginx to proxy and rewrite domain names?

Tags: nginx, proxy, rewrite

Due to the Corona situation all our campuses are closed and we try to find ways to let our students access external library services with ip-range restrictions.

We want to have something like this on the proxy service: https://libdb.net.proxy.mysite.org/whatever will give you the content of https://libdb.net/whatever and libdb.net will be tricked to believe all accesses come from proxy.mysite.org and all links under libdb.net will get rewritten accordingly. And this must work for a lot of domains. In principle it must work for any website.

We can fix the resolving with a DNS wildcard for *.proxy.mysite.com, but I'm not able to figure out the nginx magic. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

(EZproxy seems to be able to do the trick, but until I get an answer to the price quote request we are looking for alternatives)

Answer (score 0):

Please see the snippet below:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name _;

    if ($host ~ (.+)\.proxy.mysite.com$) {
            set $proxyhost $1;
    }

    location ~ {
            proxy_set_header Host $proxyhost;
            proxy_pass https://$proxyhost/;
    }
```

}

This should work for the intended scenario. The snippet is only configured to use http, not https

Comment: Thanks, but this only works for the first page. Going to links on the first page bypasses the proxy. The same for redirects, our institutions top-level page is only redirects in js like:

`
<script>
  var hostname = top.location.host;
  if(hostname == 'www.inst.myuni.no'){
    document.write('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://www.myuni.no/inst">');
  }
`
(Sorry about the formatting)